# How to inflate or deflate a bouncy ball that lacks a standard valve?

Tags: pumps, valves

I found this bouncy ball in my garage. It is too deflated to use and too inflated to store, so I would like to inflate it or deflate it. It doesn't have a standard valve for a bike pump: the only break in the plastic shell is this solid white plug that I was unable to remove.

[image: Bouncy ball]

[image: White plug on the bouncy ball]

What is this plug, and can I inflate or deflate the ball?

Comment: A quick jab with a knife will permanently deflate it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, normally you can pull those plugs out - takes a strong grip or « folding » the ball to be able to push on the inner end of the plug...

Here is a photo with such a plug taken out:

[image: Photo of plug out of the ball]

Comment: How do you then inflate the ball and replace the plug?

Comment: You fill it up (mine had a foot pump) with a tapered nozzle, and then you quickly put the plug back in before too much air leaks back out.

Comment: I was able to easily push on the inner end of the plug when the ball was partially deflated, to pump it again as per @hazzey's comment. When fully inflated, I was also able to push slightly on the inner end of the plug with a strong grip and then pull it out with pliers.